# Custom 404 Basic Page in Drupal 7 Has Blank Title Tag

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have created a basic page in drupal 7 to use as my 404.  I configured under Configuration -> System -> Site Information to use this page and when an unknown URL is entered, it does indeed display this page while maintaining the unknown URL.  For SEO purposes, I really want Page Not Found in the html title tags but it is missing.  If you go directly to the basic page, the title tags are correct.  Is there a setting somewhere that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I used the metatag module's configuration for the 404 page to achieve the desired title tags

Answer (score 0):

When you create a any page, you will get node id of the respective page.
In your case, you need to copy page.tpl.php file and rename new file with your node id like for example : page--node--1.tpl.php

Now, put below code in your newly created template file and clear the cache.

```
if($title) {
 print $title;
}
```